# Pass and Get Json String to Spring Controller

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I want to pass and Get Json String From Controller.
I want to call controller by passing json String and also want to get json String at Controller.
Is there any way to do this.
I have 2 values in my url parameter :: api=asdf23&&jsonstr={"name":"myname","age":"20"}
How can i get these two parameters at controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/GetJSON", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String GetJSON(
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            @RequestParam(value = "api") String apiKey,
            @RequestParam(value = "jsonstr") String json)
            throws ParseException {
        System.out.println("JSON :: "+json);
        return json;
    }
```

Comment: Which problem do you have with your current code ?

Comment: Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986

Comment: Note that `&&` should probably be `&` .

Answer (score 1):

Create a pojo having 2 properties name and age

```
public class Test{
private String name;
private Integer age;
//getter and setters
}
```

then modify your controller to accept json in requestbody and change the request method to post

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/GetJSON", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")

public @ResponseBody String GetJSON(
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            @RequestParam(value = "api") String apiKey,
            @RequestBody Testjson testJson)
            throws ParseException {
```

Comment: Why change *GET* to *POST*

Comment: if you are using requestbody then request method should be post

Comment: Thanks.So how can i call this controller using URL?http://localhost:8080/sajan-spr-hib/GetJSON?api=asdf23&&jsonstr={"name":"myname","age":"20"}

Comment: For POSt methods, you can not use browser url, to call the post url, you can use POST MAN or write java code

Comment: @SpringLearner The question is how does the GET method accept the json string argument, and I don't think it should be changed to post

Comment: @RequestBody(value = "jsonstr") Test Testjson Got error at  "value"

Comment: Error is Soleved.I change post method to get.But how can i call this post controller from postman?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not using URL parameter to pass the whole JSON object, rather use POST method and put JSON in the body. However, if you have reasons to use GET with json as url parameter, take help from this link to [encode](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) Http URL properly.

For your case, your JSON object will look like this:
`api%3Dasdf23%26jsonstr%3D%7B%22name%22%3A%22myname%22%2C%22age%22%3A%2220%22%7D`

Answer (score 0):

api=asdf23**&&**jsonstr={"name":"myname","age":"20"}

You only need one &

Answer (score 0):

you can also use gson 2.2.2 jar

```
RequestMapping(value = "/GetJSON", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String GetJSON(
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam(value = "api") String apiKey)
        throws ParseException {
      Gson gson=new Gson();

      Emp emp=new Emp();
        String  json =gson.tojson(emp);


    System.out.println("JSON :: "+json);
    return json;
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pass the JSON HTTP Request**

1. using the body as a POST request.
2. using url encode.

below just for example :

jsonstr={"name":"myname","age":"20"}
url :80/GetJSON?jsonstr=%7B%22name%22%3A%22myname%22%2C%22age%22%3A%2220%22%7D

for more information on URL encoding refer below

> Percent-encoding, also known as URL encoding, is a mechanism for
>   encoding information in a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) under
>   certain circumstances. Although it is known as URL encoding it is, in
>   fact, used more generally within the main Uniform Resource Identifier
>   (URI) set, which includes both Uniform Resource Locator (URL) and
>   Uniform Resource Name (URN). As such, it is also used in the
>   preparation of data of the application/x-www-form-urlencoded media
>   type, as is often used in the submission of HTML form data in HTTP
>   requests.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding